# Swift 5.5 Concurrency: creating a task with custom error type

Tags: swift, xcode13, swift5, swift-concurrency

I need to use my own custom error enum in tasks that I create:

```
enum MyError: Error {
 case someError
}

var myTask: Task<MyModel, MyError> = Task { () throws -> MyModel in
            // in case of an error: 
            // throw .someError
            // ... perform some work
            return MyModel()
        }
```

but I got the following error at the beginning of Task initializer:
`Referencing initializer 'init(priority:operation:)' on 'Task' requires the types 'MyError' and 'Error' be equivalent`.

How can I restrict the `Task` to only throw errors that are of my custom error type `MyError` ?

Comment: Why declare the type as `Task<MyModel, MyError>` in the first place?

Comment: trying to tell the compiler that I need to use `MyError`

Comment: You're not quite getting what I'm asking. Nothing stops you from declaring `Task<MyModel, Error>` or event omitting the declaration altogether. You can throw whatever you want to throw.

Comment: I need to declare `Task<MyModel, MyError>` not `Task<MyModel, Error>`

Comment: No, you don't "need" to. You _want_ to. There's a big difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Omit the unnecessary type declaration:

```
var myTask = Task { () throws -> MyModel in
    // in case of an error:
    throw MyError.someError
    // ... perform some work
    return MyModel()
}
```

The compiler implicitly (and rightly) types `myTask` as a `Task<MyModel, Error>`. The compiler doesn't care that what you throw is a MyError, because that's a form of Error.

---

Okay, I see now that the issue is merely that you asked the wrong question. You want to know *why* you can't declare this Task as a `Task<MyModel,MyError>`.

The reason is because of how this initializer is declared:

```
extension Task where Failure == Error {
    public init(priority: TaskPriority? = nil, operation: @escaping @Sendable () async throws -> Success)
}
```

Do you see? This initializer is available only `where Failure == Error`. That's `==`, not `:`. Using this initializer doesn't require that the Failure type be *an* Error, it requires that it *be* Error.

Comment: I know that I can use it this way, but the error enums in my app are numerous as well the created tasks, I need a way to statically tell the compiler that a specific task should only throw `MyError` but not any other type of `Error`.

Comment: If you know the answer, why are you asking the question?

Comment: OK, wait, I see the problem: you've asked the wrong question. I'll answer the question you _should_ have asked.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've edited the question text a little bit to be clearer

Comment: Well, as for "How can I restrict the Task to only throw errors that are of my custom error type MyError", you can't.  But that's no big surprise. An ordinary `throws` function declaration cannot specify what type of thing it throws.

Comment: Unfortunately this is so true at least until up this moment of time. Well, this is where `Combine` shines when I declare something like: `func getData() -> AnyPublisher<SomeDataType, MyError>` then my code is forced to only emit `MyError` errors.

Comment: You can certainly write code that forces itself to emit only MyError errors! If your question is how to do that, ask a new question asking that. But the point is, you cannot use the Task generic Failure type as your way of doing it. If you think this is wrong, file a bug with Apple.

Comment: I'm (also) surprised that `Task`, unlike `Result`, does not support a `Failure` that is `some Error` rather than just `any Error` or `Never`. This seems like it would fit well with the existing API and could be provided with a `Task.init(_ priority: TaskPriority = nil, task: () -> Result<Success, Failure>)` initialiser, I think? It would support typed Failure in the way `Result` does.